# how can I implement UNNSET(SELECT NAME FROM NAMES); in spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

```
Select * Id IN UNNSET(@IDS)
```

And

```
UNNSET(SELECT NAME FROM NAMES);
```

In this query `UNNEST(@IDS)` is working as I'm passing IDS as List<String>. But `UNNSET(SELECT NAME FROM NAMES)` is not working in spanner. how can I implement this in spanner?

Comment: Can you please provide the query and the error returned? The following worked for me: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField IN UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT name FROM Names));

Comment: Select * from  EMP where ID IN (@IDS) AND NAME IN (select Name from  EMP where Name = @name)  this is actual query in DB2
 I have modified to

Select * from  EMP where ID IN UNNEST(@IDS) AND NAME IN (select Name from  EMP where Name = @name)  but it is  returning null while implementing in java code but same query is working while running in spanner
@IDS - LIST<String> IDS

Comment: Have you tried running the query from the Cloud Console? What does it return? Or is the issue that the same query returns results from the Console or glcoud, but not through the java client?

Comment: Iam geting result in gcloud console but in java it is returning [] as output

Answer (score 0):

A small comment on your question is that you have misspelled `UNNEST` (as `UNNSET`). I will assume that this was a mistake when asking the question, so I will disregard it.

Given the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Names (
  Id INT64 NOT NULL,
  Names ARRAY<STRING(MAX)> NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(Id);

CREATE TABLE SingleNames (
  Id INT64 NOT NULL,
  Name STRING(MAX),
) PRIMARY KEY(Id)
```

We can perform an `IN` query like so:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SingleNames 
WHERE Name IN UNNEST((SELECT n.Names FROM Names n WHERE n.Id = 1))
```

Note the double parenthesis within the `UNNEST` call, that is required so that the query is interpreted as an expression (which is the required argument for the `UNNEST` call).

We can query that using the Java client like so:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = databaseClient
        .singleUse()
        .executeQuery(Statement
            .newBuilder("SELECT * FROM SingleNames WHERE Name IN UNNEST((SELECT n.Names FROM Names n WHERE n.Id = @id))")
            .bind("id")
            .to(1L)
            .build())
  ) {
    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getLong("Id") + ", " + rs.getString("Name"));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Will it work in named queries
@Query("SELECT  SingleName As SingleName, .n* FROM Names n JOINS on SingleNames sn
WHERE SingleName IN UNNEST (@SingleNames) AND Name IN UNNEST((SELECT n.Names FROM Names n WHERE n.Id = @id)").                
   List<Entity>findByNameANDId(@Param("SingleNames")List<String>Single Names,@Param("id")int id);

Comment: I assume you are working with Spring-data. If so, it should be possible to bind a List<String> to a parameter in a named query. So, the following is valid: "SELECT sn.* FROM SingleNames sn WHERE sn.Name IN UNNEST(@names) AND sn.Name IN UNNEST((SELECT n.Names FROM Names n WHERE n.Id = @id))". Notice that you still have some errors in your original query, like "JOINS" not being a valid key.